# Bot framework- static menu

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

Im creating a chatbot using bot framework (c#), I have added a suggested actions on onturnasync method to show up to the user as a menu, but when i run the bot the suggested actions method will run for each activity and show the menus to the user since i called it in onturnasync method, is there any method or way i can add this suggested menu as a static or to load only once when the user joins the conversation, (note I tried called it in onmemberaddedasync method , but it shows only at the starting and disappears as the operation continues).

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what behavior you'd like to achieve? It seems like the `OnMemberAddedAsync` method is doing its job by showing the suggested actions only when someone joins.

Comment: yes it does job , but the menu disappears after the first activity & i need the menu to stay untill the end of conversation, (static menu). Please suggest

Comment: So you want the menu to pop-up after every interaction? Or is this a web chat where you just want the menu to be available on the side? 

You could prompt the user after every dialog with the menu. Could you clarify what exactly you want, and perhaps add some code samples?

Comment: @AP01 , Since im calling the menu in onturnasync it pop -ups after each interaction, I would want it to be static only once after member is added , (Already tried in onmemberaddedasync, but it appears only once at the intial of the conversation then disappears). `public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) { await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken); await SendSuggestedActionsAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken); }`

Comment: hi @AP01 can you also tell how to prompt the user with the menu after every dialog?

Comment: You can simply add the prompt as a dialog step at the end of each dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The way I probably make this "Static Menu" is using a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Currently I have a chatbot originally developed for a Webchat. Some sprint later, client requested to include MS Teams Channel. That create me some problems, because some features like suggested action is not supported. So I used middleware to replace suggested actions with Hero Cards, when bot is in MS Teams Channel.

What I do in your place is create a middleware and append your static menu to the message before send.

You can check the documentation for more details about [middlewares.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

If I have some free time this week, I will create a simple bot to show how you can do it.

Best regard!

### Update 25/6/2022

I created a repository with a sample bot [here](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu)

The sample bot is a bot with three component dialogs:

- [Root Dialog (menu)](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu/blob/master/StaticMenuBot/RootDialog.cs)
- [User Profile Dialog](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu/blob/master/StaticMenuBot/UserProfileDialog.cs)
- [Weather Dialog](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu/blob/master/StaticMenuBot/WeatherDialog.cs)
- Cancel Command (not an actual dialog)

To understand how the middleware work go to [**StaticMenuMiddleware**](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu/blob/master/StaticMenuBot/StaticMenuMiddleware.cs).

### How to replicate this in your project?

1. Create a middleware for your static menu. In my case the logic look for the last element in the activity array and append the static menu as Suggested Actions.
2. Add this middleware as a singleton in your [Startup.cs](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu/blob/master/StaticMenuBot/Startup.cs)
3. Modify your [BotAdapter](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu/blob/master/StaticMenuBot/AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs)'s constructor so it expect an IMiddleware as a dependency. Is possible to pass a list of IMiddleware but... is out of scope in this sample.
4. Inside your Bot Adapter's constructor add the following line `Use(<middleware_variable>)`, where `middleware_variable` is the name of your dependency.

Hope this sample code result helpful to everyone.
If any question arise, I will try to answer as soon as possible.

Comment: For clarification this is assuming you want the "static menu" appear persistently on the chat. As far as I know is not possible to load the menu one time and persist during all the conversation.

Comment: Yes i want to stay the menu persistently or on some button click i would want to pop up the menu, Please show this in your simple bot , it would be healpful. regards

Comment: @di007 I update this answer to include the sample bot repository and some instructions. If any question arise I will try to answer soon as possible :)

Comment: I have checked your sample and noticed that the middleware is loading for each turn, what I wanted is to stick the suggested actions conversation and not loading each time. can this be achievable?  and also will this suggested actions visible in teams channel if i integrate it to teams channel?

Comment: As far as  I know there is no other way to  stick the suggested actions on the conversation the first time and persist during all the conversation. The only trick I know is what I shown in the sample code.  If you plan to use your bot in MS Teams you will need to change this menu to another format like  HeroCard, because [Suggested Action is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json). If you plan to provide this options in a Webchat you can add buttons to your UI.

Comment: Another options specifically for MS Teams is to use a "Bot menu". You will need to use the AppStudio app in MS Teams and go to "Capabilities > Bots > Bot menus" and add your options there. For example in the "Personal tab" you can add commands. See a tutorial [here](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/clients-and-channels/tutorials/enable-teams/6-add-commands/)

Comment: Here another userful [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-commands-menu?tabs=desktop%2Cdotnet) about adding Menu in MS Teams using AppStudio

Comment: is there any sample how to add buttons to webchat UI?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event) an example using the Microsoft Botframework Webchat and [here](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/04.api/d.post-activity-event/) a demo. If I have free time this weekend I will try to create something similar with my [sample bot](https://github.com/sempjc/BotWithStaticMenu).

Comment: Yes please , can you create one sample bot and share it would be really helpful!

Comment: hi @Jean, waiting for your sample bot about adding button to UI

Comment: hi @Jean. waiting for your sample code